# QEMU/KVM Black Screens When Attempting GPU Passthrough to Windows Guest OS

Tags: virtual-machine, nvidia, kvm, qemu

So I have Linux Mint 20.2 installed on a [ROG Zephyrus M15](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/asus-rog-zephyrus-m15-15-6-4k-ultra-hd-gaming-laptop-intel-core-i7-16gb-memory-nvidia-geforce-rtx-2060-1tb-ssd-prism-black/6403817.p?skuId=6403817) and I'm trying to passthrough the RTX GPU to a Windows 10 VM through QEMU/KVM. I've tried following multiple guides including [the wiki from this GitLab page](https://gitlab.com/risingprismtv/single-gpu-passthrough) and [this one from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDMoEvf8Q18). The result is a black screen with different behavior depending on the profile my laptop is in (a couple lines of output are displayed before a black screen with NVIDIA (Performance Mode) where those outputted lines do not display with Intel (Power Saving Mode)).

I will be linking the [grub Pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/BiKyWg8W) and the [virsh configuration here](https://pastebin.com/tYR0NMRJ). In the GitLab wiki, it had a section setting up a log file so I feel it would be good to [link it here](https://pastebin.com/SmYLWhqY) as well (I tried to read the file, but I could not understand what was going on).

I am new when it comes to asking questions on forums so if any more information is needed, feel free to ask. As always, I appreciate any help provided.